# access denied by system hololens 2 research mode

Tags: uwp, hololens

I'm currently trying to fetch IMU data from Hololens 2 through ResearchMode. It is OK with camera consents but surprisigly IMU consents denying by the system without any prompt showing up. (implementation is quite similar compare to the camera consent)
I wonder if any one has any idea what have I've done wrong?

I uninstalled the application multiple times but prompt always pops up only for camera and not the IMU!

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f09Nq.jpg

Comment: Did you refer to this sample - [HoloLens2ForCV/Samples/SensorVisualization at main · microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/tree/main/Samples/SensorVisualization)? And as said in the README, please pay attention to the Consent Prompts in Docs/ResearchMode-ApiDoc.pdf - [HoloLens2ForCV/Docs/ECCV2020-Tutorial/ECCV2020-ResearchMode-Api.pdf at main · microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/blob/main/Docs/ECCV2020-Tutorial/ECCV2020-ResearchMode-Api.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I know, I am responding so late and I apologize for that. Actually yes, I checked them multiple times and couldn't firgure out why is this happeing. But as it wasn't the only way, later I had found suitible basis writen in advance to build my code upon. Thank you.